# Running a Spring Boot app from Docker is not working

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker

I have a rather strange problem. I am trying to run a Spring Boot app via docker. So here are my steps.

1) I am creating a Dockerfile.

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install -y java

VOLUME /tmp
ADD /spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
ENTRYPOINT [“java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
jar","/myapp.jar"]
```

In this file I am installing java. I am also using the jar file of the app called **spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**

2) The next step is to build an image. So I am typing

```
tmp theodosiostziomakas$ docker build -t spring-boot-docker .
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

So the image was built correctly.

3) Now I am running that image to generate a container. So

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-docker
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

You can see that a container is generated. But when I type

```
$ docker ps
```

the container_id is not visible and when I type **localhost:8080** in the browser the app is not running at all. Why is this happening? Any ideas? How to fix it?

Comment: run docker ps --all and check whether that container exited while ago.

Comment: @HansikaMadushanWeerasena created 3 minutes ago, exited also 3 minutes ago!

Comment: Docker docker logs of that container has any output.

Comment: @HansikaMadushanWeerasena Yes but why does this container exits?

Comment: What’s the output of log

Comment: @HansikaMadushanWeerasena CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
8b5b5c562c11        spring-boot-docker   "/bin/sh -c [“java\",…"   37 seconds ago      Exited (1) 36 seconds ago                       flamboyant_ramanujan

Comment: @HansikaMadushanWeerasena It doesn't run in any port (8080 in my case) as it exits straigh after run.

Comment: instead of running it in detached mod, try running it 'docker run -p 8080:8080 spring-boot-docker' directly, this way you may see error log that causes the exit. But apparently your spring boot application crashing and because of that docker containers shuts itself down.

Comment: @MuratGüvenç I am getting this: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: are there any other log? which file causing this syntax error?

Comment: @MuratGüvenç I had a syntax error in the Dockerfile. now it's fixed

Comment: ok so it is working now. Then can you post the solution and mark it as answer

Comment: Please post formatted text, rather than screenshots of text. Screenshots make it difficult to help without a large monitor to read on, and make it unlikely for others to find your question in a search of the error message.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the posted Dockerfile the file you are using then there is a wrong quote sign just before java:

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install -y java

VOLUME /tmp

ADD /spring-boot-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar

RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myapp.jar"]
```